# How to use a openvdb (parallel) foreach accessing multiple grids?

Tags: c++, foreach, parallel-processing, openvdb

I have an openvdb grid that I would like to iterate using a functor and openvdb::tools::foreach.

```
//the grid I am iterating on
Grid G;

//the operator used to update each single voxel of G
struct Functor{
  inline void operator()(const Grid::ValueOnCIter& iter) const {
  }
};
```

If the operation involved only G I could have simply called

```
  Functor op;
  openvdb::tools::foreach(visibleGrid->cbeginValueOn(), op, true, true);
```

At each voxel (iteration) though I need to access and modify additional grid(s) based on the computed value of the iteration step.

My inital solution involved providing to the functor the accessor of the additional grid(s):

```
struct Functor{
  Grid2::Accessor grid2_accessor;

  Functor( Grid2::Accessor& a) : grid2_accessor(a){}

  inline void operator()(const Grid::ValueOnCIter& iter) const {
      //use grid2_accessor based on iter.getCoord()
  }
};
```

the accessor is provided to Functor at construction time and moreover each thread of the parallel for get a copy of the functor:

```
  Functor op(G2->getAccessor() );
  openvdb::tools::foreach(G1->cbeginValueOn(), op, true, **false**);
```

Unfortunately this solution does not work since:

- the accessor must not be const to be accessed
- but Functor::operator() must be a const method to be used by tools::foreach

A second **dirty** solution was to declare the Functor accessor copy as mutable. This solution does not work in Debug due to an openvdb assertion failing (most probably a memory leak).

Is there a solution to the problem? E.g. a tools::foreach that does not require operator() to be const.

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to use the same `ValueAccessor` in different threads. Instead, you want to have unique `ValueAccessor`s for each thread but share the underlying tree.

Define your `Functor` like this instead:

```
struct Functor {
    Grid2& mGrid2;
    Functor(Grid2& grid2) : mGrid2(grid2) {}

    void operator()(const Grid::ValueOnCIter& iter) const {
        Grid2::Accessor grid2Acc(grid2.getAccessor()); // This is allowed because Grid2 is a reference
        // Do what you want
    } 
}
```

The reason you can't find a non-const version of the operator is because the underlying implementation relies on `tbb`. The motivation they give in the [tbb documentation](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/parallel_for.html) is:

> Because the body object might be copied, its operator() should not modify the body. Otherwise the modification might or might not become visible to the thread that invoked parallel_for, depending upon whether operator() is acting on the original or a copy. As a reminder of this nuance, parallel_for requires that the body object's operator() be declared const.

Because of this you should not expect a non-const version any time soon.

EDIT: As noted in comments it is possible to reuse the cache in the `ValueAccessor`. However, as it is now a member of the class you will have problem to modify the tree using it in the operator (as `setValue` is non-const). If you know no one else is writing to the same memory place you can do a small hack:

```
struct Functor {
    Grid2::ValueAccessor mGrid2Acc;
    Functor(Grid2::ValueAccessor grid2Acc) : mGrid2Acc(grid2Acc) {}

    void operator()(const Grid::ValueOnCIter& iter) const {
        const Grid2::ValueType& v = mGrid2Acc.getValue(iter.getCoord());
        Grid2::ValueType& non_const_v = const_cast<Grid2::ValueType&>(v);
        // modify the value as you please, however a race condition will occur
        // if more than 1 thread write to the same location
    } 
}
```

I would still prefer the first solution. You can cache a certain leaf node by calling `probeLeaf(openvdb::Coord& ijk)` on the accessor.

Comment: Good point! By instantiating the accessor every time though I am losing the last cached tree path accessed. This gives me a performance penality

Comment: @Pierluigi That is true. What I should have added as well is that you could just pass the accessor by value instead of by reference, that way you keep the cache intact.